Managing Nginx vHost Conf Files with Ansible
I'm new to the automation world and I'm stuck trying to figure out how I can automate and maintain Nginx conf files for the vhost I manage using Ansible.
For example, normally I would create a conf file domain1_com.conf and domain2_com.conf etc etc for each domain. I was doing this manually so this is what I tried to do:
First I created an inventory file for the host(s) running Nginx and created a host_var to be exact. In that host_var I created a list for the domains like this:
domains:
   - domain1
   - domain2
   - domain3
   - domain4

From there, I tried to create a template file for the default configs for new domains:
server {

    root /var/www/{{ domains }}/public_html;
    index index.html index.htm index.php;

    server_name {{ domains }} www.{{ domains }};

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/{{ domains }}_access.log;
    error_log   /var/log/nginx/{{ domains }}_error.log;

    location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

}

These were the steps I used in the playbook:
- name: Deploy/Update Virtual Hosts for Nginx
  block:

    - name: Create site configuration directories
      ansible.builtin.file:
        path: "{{ item }}"
        state: directory
        recurse: yes
      with_items:
        - /etc/nginx/sites-available
        - /etc/nginx/sites-enabled

    - name: Create vhost directories
      ansible.builtin.file:
        path: /var/www/{{ item }}/public_html/
        state: directory
        mode: '0755'
        owner: www-data
        group: www-data
      loop: "{{ domains }}"

    - name: Deploy Nginx Configuration
      ansible.builtin.copy:
        src: nginx.conf
        dest: /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

    - name: Check for Active vhost Configurations
      ansible.builtin.stat:
        path: "/etc/nginx/sites-available/{{ item }}.conf"
      register: nginx_configs
      loop: "{{ domains }}"

    - name: Deploy Non-SSL vHost Configurations
      ansible.builtin.template:
        src: vhost_config.j2
        dest: "/etc/nginx/sites-available/{{ item.item }}.conf"
        owner: root
        group: root
      when: not item.stat.exists
      loop: "{{ nginx_configs.results }}"

    - name: Create Configuration Symlinks
      ansible.builtin.file:
        src: "/etc/nginx/sites-available/{{ domains }}.conf"
        dest: "/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/{{ domains }}.conf"
        state: link
      loop: "{{ domains }}"

    - name: Reload Nginx
      ansible.builtin.systemd:
        name: nginx
        state: reloaded

I was hoping that for the "Check for Active vhost Configurations" when it checks and doesn't find a vhost config for a new domain, it would deploy the vhost_config.j2 for the new domain(s) only. The file is being generated with the proper file name for example domain1.com.conf however, the content of that file contains ALL of the domain names listed and not just the new domain(s).
vhost_config.js deployed as /etc/nginx/sites-available/domain1.com.conf
server {

    root /var/www/['domain1.com', 'domain2.com', 'domain3.com', 'domain4.com', 'domain5.com', 'domain6.com']/public_html;
    index index.html index.htm index.php;

    server_name ['domain1.com', 'domain2.com', 'domain3.com', 'domain4.com', 'domain5.com', 'domain6.com'] www.['domain1.com', 'domain2.com', 'domain3.com', 'domain4.com', 'domain5.com', 'domain6.com'];

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/['domain1.com', 'domain2.com', 'domain3.com', 'domain4.com', 'domain5.com', 'domain6.com']_access.log;
    error_log   /var/log/nginx/['domain1.com', 'domain2.com', 'domain3.com', 'domain4.com', 'domain5.com', 'domain6.com']_error.log;

    location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

}

Outside of what I posted above, I have also tried to do a for loop but I couldn't figure out how to tell it to use the results from the "Check for Active Nginx Configurations" to only deploy for domain names as the content for the vhost_config.j2 it generates one per domain name.
For example:
vhost_config.j2 for domain1.com.conf and domain2.com.conf
When the play runs, it should create two files domain1.com.conf and domain2.com.conf and each one should have {{ domains }} or the needed variable there to only print out one new domain name per file so domain1.com.conf should only have domain1.com inside of it and no other domain.
I'm using Ansible version [core 2.15.12] and Python version 3.9.2 and the host being deployed to is using Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS.
Sorry for such a long message. Please let me know if there is any additional information I can provide and thank you to all for your time and help!

As far as I understand your example currently you'll probably need to change your template file, exchange domains with item.item.
A minimal example playbook
---
- hosts: localhost
  become: false
  gather_facts: false

  vars:

    domains:
      - example.org
      - example.net
      - example.com

  tasks:

    - name: Check for Active vhost Configurations
      ansible.builtin.stat:
        path: "{{ item }}.conf"
      loop: "{{ domains }}"
      register: nginx_configs

    - debug:
        var: nginx_configs.results

    - name: Deploy Non-SSL vHost Configurations
      debug:
        msg: |
          server {

              root /var/www/{{ item.item }}/public_html;
              index index.html index.htm index.php;

              server_name {{ item.item }} www.{{ item.item }};

              access_log  /var/log/nginx/{{ item.item }}_access.log;
              error_log   /var/log/nginx/{{ item.item }}_error.log;

              location / {
                  try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
              }

          }
      when: not item.stat.exists
      loop: "{{ nginx_configs.results }}"
      loop_control:
        label: "{{ item.item }}"

will result into an output of
TASK [Check for Active vhost Configurations] *************
ok: [localhost] => (item=example.org)
ok: [localhost] => (item=example.net)
ok: [localhost] => (item=example.com)

TASK [debug] *********************************************
ok: [localhost] =>
  nginx_configs.results:
  - ansible_loop_var: item
    changed: false
    failed: false
    invocation:
      module_args:
        checksum_algorithm: sha1
        follow: false
        get_attributes: true
        get_checksum: true
        get_md5: false
        get_mime: true
        path: example.org.conf
    item: example.org
    stat:
      exists: false
  - ansible_loop_var: item
    changed: false
    failed: false
    invocation:
      module_args:
        checksum_algorithm: sha1
        follow: false
        get_attributes: true
        get_checksum: true
        get_md5: false
        get_mime: true
        path: example.net.conf
    item: example.net
    stat:
      exists: false
  - ansible_loop_var: item
    changed: false
    failed: false
    invocation:
      module_args:
        checksum_algorithm: sha1
        follow: false
        get_attributes: true
        get_checksum: true
        get_md5: false
        get_mime: true
        path: example.com.conf
    item: example.com
    stat:
      <omitted>
      exists: true
      <omitted>

TASK [Deploy Non-SSL vHost Configurations] ***************
ok: [localhost] => (item=example.org) =>
  msg: |-
    server {

        root /var/www/example.org/public_html;
        index index.html index.htm index.php;

        server_name example.org www.example.org;

        access_log  /var/log/nginx/example.org_access.log;
        error_log   /var/log/nginx/example.org_error.log;

        location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }

    }
ok: [localhost] => (item=example.net) =>
  msg: |-
    server {

        root /var/www/example.net/public_html;
        index index.html index.htm index.php;

        server_name example.net www.example.net;

        access_log  /var/log/nginx/example.net_access.log;
        error_log   /var/log/nginx/example.net_error.log;

        location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }

    }

Otherwise you would need to identify on which element of the list you are during loop and get the corresponding element from the domains list only.
Without changing the template file you could "overwrite" the variable domains for the task only, like in
    - name: Deploy Non-SSL vHost Configurations
      debug:
        msg: |
          server {

              server_name {{ domains }} www.{{ domains }};

          }
      when: not item.stat.exists
      loop: "{{ nginx_configs.results }}"
      loop_control:
        label: "{{ item.item }}"
      vars:
        domains: "{{ item.item }}"

resulting into an output of
TASK [Deploy Non-SSL vHost Configurations] ***************
ok: [localhost] => (item=example.org) =>
  msg: |-
    server {

        server_name example.org www.example.org;

    }
ok: [localhost] => (item=example.net) =>
  msg: |-
    server {

        server_name example.net www.example.net;

    }

See Understanding variable precedence if it would fit to your needs, as it depends on where domains became defined.

Hello @U88D
Thank you for your reply! I'm a little confused my apologies. I updated the steps as you suggested or I believe I did but the error is a bit different now:
"get_checksum": true, "get_md5": false, "get_mime": true, "path": "/etc/nginx/sites-available/domain1.conf"}}, "item": "domain1", "stat": {"exists": false}}, "msg": "Destination directory /etc/nginx/sites-available/{'changed': False, 'stat': {'exists': False}, 'invocation': {'module_args': {'path': '/etc/nginx/sites-available does not exist"}
The directory does indeed exist and is used in the check before

@HOVNetworksLLC, could be a permission problem, running onRemote Node vs. Control Node, etc. ... That kind of error and the debugging seems to unrelated to this specific question and answer.

Here is a link to the full code used, jinja and full error. It is complaining about the conditional nginx_config.stat.exists. It's like I move one thing another comes. But this is the process of learning which is the fun part.
https://pastebin.com/q5aXtnD8

@HOVNetworksLLC, please update your initial question by editing or ask a new other question. Should I also consider that the steps provided do not answer your question?

@U88OD my apologies you did answer the question I just need to figure out on my end how to apply it to the code I have. I thought I did but that is when I got that error mentioned above in the link. I will continue to debug and use the methods provided and see if I can figure it out and post the answer when I do I'm sure it is something silly on my end. Thank you very much for your time and help!
